# Mustache.js with arrays, exception for the last item

Tags: javascript, mustache

```
var template = "multi: {{#answerVOs}}{{answer}}; {{/answerVOs}}";
```

//need => multi: option1; option2; option3   (no semicolon and space at the end)

```
var json = {
"answerVOs": [ 
  { "answer" : "option 1"
  },
  { "answer" : "option 2"
  },
  { "answer" : "option 3"
  }
]
};

document.getElementById("answers").innerHTML = Mustache.to_html(template, json);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/casadev/GEbe8/1/

I need the last item in the array to be displayed without the semicolon and space, any ideas.

Edit: PHP Code

```
class ChoiceVO extends \ValueObject {

public $id;
public $question;
public $answer;
public $answerformat;
public $fraction;
public $feedback;
public $feedbackformat;

public $replace = "function () { var result = ''; for( var i = 0; i < this.answers.length; i++ ) { result += this.answers[i].answer + (i !== this.answers.length - 1 ? '; ' : '');}return result;}";

function __construct($args=null) {
    parent::__construct($args);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Mustache.js documentation on their Github page it is possible to pass a function into the data and call it using template tags. So what you could do is something like this (note that this code is untested):

```
var template = 'multi: {{listAnswers}}';
var context = {
    answers: [
        { answer: 'Answer 1' },
        { answer: 'Answer 2' },
        { answer: 'Answer 3' }
    ],
    listAnswers: function () {
        var result = '';
        for( var i = 0; i < this.answers.length; i++ ) {
            result += this.answers[i].answer + (i !== this.answers.length - 1 ? '; ' : '');
        }
        return result;
    }
};

document.getElementById('answers').innerHTML = Mustache.render(template, context);
```

### After some feedback

To add the function after the JSON has been parsed do this:

```
var json = '{"answers":[{"answer":"Answer 1"},{"answer":"Answer 2"},{"answer":"Answer 3"}]}'; // Server response
var context = JSON.parse(json); // JSON parsed to JavaScript Object

// Add method in JavaScript, NOT PHP.
context.listAnswers = function () {
    var result = '';
    for( var i = 0; i < this.answers.length; i++ ) {
        result += this.answers[i].answer + (i !== this.answers.length - 1 ? '; ' : '');
    }
    return result;
};

document.getElementById('answers').innerHTML = Mustache.render(template, context);
```

Comment: Thanks Jon for the answer, I've been looking into a function based solution but now the problem is the JSON is getting generated from PHP, and if I add a function, it's coming as a string down the wire, for instance listAnswers = "function() { /*...*/ };"